# VB.Net make a image in background task using Win2d

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-runtime, win2d

Dependency : Win2D

I am trying to generate a Livetile image from background task.
However, the generated PNG file only looks transparent, no single dot is painted at all.

So, I simplified the important code as below to test, yet no result was changed.

I imported `Microsoft.Canvas.Graphics(+Effects,+Text)`,

```
Dim device As CanvasDevice = New CanvasDevice()
                Dim width = 150, height = 150

                Using renderTarget = New CanvasRenderTarget(device, width, height, 96)
                    Dim ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession()
                    'ds = DrawTile(ds, w, h)

                    Dim xf As CanvasTextFormat = New CanvasTextFormat()
                    xf.HorizontalAlignment = CanvasHorizontalAlignment.Left
                    xf.VerticalAlignment = CanvasVerticalAlignment.Top
                    xf.FontSize = 12

                    renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession.Clear(Colors.Red)
                    ds.Clear(Colors.Blue)
                    ds.DrawText("hi~", 1, 1, Colors.Black, xf)
                    renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession.DrawText("hi~", 1, 1, Colors.Black, xf)


                    Await renderTarget.SaveAsync(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "_tile_150x150.png"))

                End Using
```

The file is created, but it's filled with neither Red or Blue. No text at all. It's transparent with only 150x150 pixel canvas.

Is there any problem with the code? or any other reason?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CanvasDrawingSession ("ds" in your sample) needs to be Closed / Disposed before you call SaveAsync.

You can use "Using ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession()" to do this for you - put the call to SaveAsync after "End Using".

From there you should use the same "ds" rather than call "CreateDrawingSession" multiple times.